# C#/.NET: TextBox is not 'focused' after a process was initiated

Tags: c#, .net, textbox, focus, lost-focus

I am having a problem after opening the notepad once I click the button "btnSearch".

The idea is that once I clicked the button 'btnSearch', the textbox 'txtSearch' should be 'focused' even after a process was initiated/opened outside the main window.

Here's my code:

```
    private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad");
        txtSearch.Focus(); // not working
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this WPF or WinForms?

Comment: I've used WPF and WinForms at the same time. Is it a problem?

Comment: I'll bet you're loosing focus to the application you're opening.

Comment: try minimising notepad once you start it. This may return focus to your application or try switching focus to your application instead

Comment: @Cen: yes it is.
@Veer: is there a way to switch focus to the main window instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below is the code you would need.  This could be done through interop services

```
    private void setwind()
    {

        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad");

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);  //  To give time for the notepad to open

        if (GetForegroundWindow() != this.Handle)
        {
            SetForegroundWindow(this.Handle);
        }
    }


    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
```

Answer (score 4):

In your Page_Load event try

```
Control c= GetPostBackControl(this.Page);

if(c != null)
{
   if (c.Id == "btnSearch")
   {
       SetFocus(txtSearch);
   }

}
```

Then add this to your page or BasePage or whatever

```
public static Control GetPostBackControl(Page page)
{
     Control control = null;
     string ctrlname = page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
     if (ctrlname != null && ctrlname != String.Empty)
     {
          control = page.FindControl(ctrlname);

     }
     else
     {
          foreach (string ctl in page.Request.Form)
          {
               Control c = page.FindControl(ctl);
               if(c is System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button)
               {
                   control = c;
                   break;
               }
          }

     }
     return control;
}
```

Comment: Is the 'Control' under System.Windows.Forms.Control or System.Windows.Controls.Control ?

Comment: This answer appears to be referring to ASP.Net, rather than WinForms (or WPF)

Comment: Yes, sorry, this is an ASP.Net example.

Comment: He didn't specify WinForms exactly, and the sample if pertinent and a simlar methodolgy could be used on a WinForm; I don't know why this is down voted. *shrug*

Comment: what is "__EVENTTARGET" here. I am calling it on a Button, how will I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
txtSearch.Select ()
txtSearch.Focus()
```

?
Is your TextBox within a GroupBox?

Comment: txt.Search.Select is not working too. I just want to 'focus' the textbox (the bar should be blinking)

Comment: the textbox is not within a groupbox

Answer (score 0):

Applications cannot "steal" focus from other applications (since Windows XP), the closest they can achieve is flashing the taskbar, which is possible via P/Invoke:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool FlashWindow(IntPtr handle, bool invert);
```

Then pass it the form's `Handle`

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `TabIndex` property.  Use a value of 0 on the control you need focused when you start the application.