# ASP.NET :: During page_load, how can I get the ID of the control that submitted the postback?

Tags: asp.net, postback

During the Page_Load, I would like to capture the control that performed the postback.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {

    }

    // Capture the control ID here.
}
```

As usual, any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For anyone who might interested in this (at least what worked for me).  [Cen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/201242/cen) provided the answer.

In your Page_Load event add:

```
Control c= GetPostBackControl(this.Page); 

if(c != null) 
{ 
    if (c.Id == "btnSearch") 
    { 
        SetFocus(txtSearch); 
    } 
}
```

Then in your basepage code add:

```
public static Control GetPostBackControl(Page page)
{
    Control control = null;
    string ctrlname = page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
    if (ctrlname != null && ctrlname != String.Empty)
    {
        control = page.FindControl(ctrlname);

    }
    else
    {
        foreach (string ctl in page.Request.Form)
        {
            Control c = page.FindControl(ctl);
            if (c is System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button)
            {
                control = c;
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    return control;
}
```

You can see the original post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558809/c-net-textbox-is-not-focused-after-a-process-was-initiated)

Hope this helps.

Comment: If there are two buttons in the same form... Will your code be able to find which one caused it...  If yes, could you please explain how?

Comment: Yes.  The control name is read from page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET")

Comment: @TheKing, I don't think what Andy replied is correct. To answer your question, according to [the article that this answer appears to be derived from](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2005/03/11/1886.aspx), the code will find the correct button. The explanation according to the article is as follows: *the Buttons render as simple input type=“submit” tags. All the button does is cause the form to submit. That's it. However, you can still get to it, just in a different way.*

Comment: *Since the button (or input) is what causes the form to submit, it is added to the items in the Form collection, along with all the other values from the submitted form. It is important to note, that other input type=“submit” tags on the form are not added to the Form collection unless it was the one that caused the form to submit. If you were to look in the Form collection for anything that is a button then that will be what caused the postback (assuming that it was a button that caused the page to submit)*

Answer (score 2):

You can usually look at `Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"]`.  This variable will be populated as the result of the postback, and will hold the UniqueID of the control that caused it.

Unfortunately this doesn't work for button or imagebutton controls.  For what looks to be a pretty robust method for getting it in these cases, you could [check out this blog post](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2005/03/11/1886.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If there's a way to do that, I'd love to know it too!

However, you can set up event handlers for each of the controls that can generate the postback, and handle events as they come in.

The problem with that is that these events are handled after Page_Load. So what you need to do in this approach is add a handler for Page_PreRender, and process the control input there. In the page life cycle, control events are after Load, but before PreRender.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Request["__EVENTTARGET"] to get the ID of the control that invoked the postback.